# My father paying my zakat

Tags: zakat

Is it allowed for my father to pay my zakat for me?

I calculated my zakat for this year, and when I recently visited, I asked him to give the money to my mother to donate (she knows some charities that she can give the money to). He said, keep the money and he'll give her the same amount on my behalf... as a gift. So basically just decided to pay my zakat.

Is this allowed?

Obviously, I can afford to pay my own zakat (because everyone can pay their own zakat). But also obviously, parents are allowed to gift money to their children.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Zakat is obligatory for every individual who can donate a certain portion of their wealth. Your father is not obligated to pay Zakat on your behalf, but doing so on your behalf with your consent is not an issue - you can pay the Zakat yourself or have someone else pay it on your behalf; as long as you have calculated your individual donation appropriately, it is fine.